# Is it possible to diff duplicate questions?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Is it possible to get a tool, or some way to get a tool that can diff duplicate questions? It would make it a lot easier for moderation when we have the other question on the same screen.

Comment: you mean to see two Q/A pages side by side, right?

Comment: I don't see how an actual diff will be of any use. If you just want to view them together, what's wrong with browser tabs?

Comment: @Cai it's just easier to check them out instead of going into the comments that mention the duplicate, open the tab, and check between the two.

Comment: @CBredlow you'd have to follow a link to get to a diff anyway. If you just want them side-by-side then there's likely an easy way to do this already (I have both a browser extension to do this *and* a standard way to do it via the OS)

Answer (score 7):

Well, considering that most duplicate questions are worded quite differently from each other, a true [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) does not really make sense.

As a workaround, consider opening the other question in a separate browser window and resize both windows. It's not *that* much work; depending on your OS it might be [built in](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027324/windows-snap-your-windows) or else there will be tools that do this for you.

Comment: As @Glorfindel hints at, many duplicates are duplicates, because of the existing question's answers.  It is up to the reviewers, to use due diligence, before flagging a question as a duplicate.